# Add a new service to existing service fabric application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

How do I add a new Stateful Service to an existing service fabric application in Visual Studio 2015? I can only see the option to add a new service fabric application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Service Fabric Application project has a Services node in the Solution Explorer in VS. You can right click on the node to add an existing service.

It's likely that you'll still need to change the application manifest manually though.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't see this before upgraded the SFTools to VS 2015. Cheers!

Comment: To add an existing SF service, add a reference to the service project in the solution, go to the SF project, right click on Services and select "Add Existing Service Fabric Service in Solution", update ApplicationManifest.xml to add new entries for the service